# rmagic: write blob string to svg

Tags: ruby, svg, rmagick

I am trying to get back my svg file from its blob. However it doesn't seem to work. I have following code and corresponding output:

```
image = Magick::Image.read("public/logo.svg").first
 => public/logo.svg SVG 64x64 64x64+0+0 DirectClass 16-bit 4kb
blob_image = Magick::Image.from_blob(image.to_blob).first
 =>  SVG 64x64 64x64+0+0 DirectClass 16-bit 187kb
blob_image.write "public/new_logo.svg"
=> public/new_logo.svg SVG 64x64 64x64+0+0 DirectClass 16-bit 260kb
```

Now if I try to open "new_logo.svg" I get following error (in gimp):

> Could not open '/some-path/public/new_logo.svg' for
>   reading: Error domain 1 code 73 on line 4051 column 20 of
>   file:///some-path/public: Couldn't find end of Start
>   Tag circle

There is also a significant increase in file size (from 4kb to 260kb). Am I doing something wrong here?